# How to keep ImageView fade in when touched?

Tags: android, animation, touch

I want to create an app in android that shows an animation when the user touches the ImageView. It should be scaled down until the user pulls his finger off the screen.

Just like windows phone icons. How can I do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Create an Handler with post delayed messages that scale the image.

When you receive the `ACTION_DOWN` start the handler (which scales the image and calls itself). When you receive the `ACTION_UP` remove all message and callbacks from the handler.

If you don't want to use handlers you can simple start a scale animation on your imageview on `ACTION_DOWN` and stop it on `ACTION_UP`. `View.clearAnimation()` or `View.animate().cancel()`

Comment: How to create Handler? @Pedro Oliveira

Comment: There are many examples on the internet. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18561687/android-animation-using-handler